# Why are my variables returning null and or 0 when using different classes?

Tags: java, class, methods, null, var

My problem is when I run the code, the variables being accessed by the final print statement is returning them as null and or 0's.

Here is my code.
**SammysContrusct**
package program7;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SammysContract {
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
static  String  contractID,rental;

static  int     minutes,hours;

static  double  totalCost;

public void printWelcome()
{       
    System.out.println("Welcome back to Sammy's Rentals! Now introducing new prices and contracts!");   
}

public String inputContract()
{
    System.out.print("Please enter your contract ID: ");
    String contractID = userInput.nextLine();       
    return contractID;      
}

public String rentalItem()
{       
    System.out.print("What would you like to rent? ");
    String rentalItem = userInput.nextLine();       
    return rentalItem;      
}

public int hourID()
{       
    System.out.print("How many hours would you like to rent it for? ");
    int hours = userInput.nextInt();        
    return hours;       
}

public int minuteID()
{       
    System.out.print("How many minutes would you like to rent it for? ");
    int minutes = userInput.nextInt();      
    return minutes;     
}

public double calculateRate()
{       
    if (hours < 3)
    {           
        totalCost = hours * 35; 

    }
    else if (hours >= 3 | hours <=5)
    {

        totalCost = hours * 30;

    }
    else if (hours >= 5 | hours <=7)
    {

        totalCost = hours * 25;

    }
    else if (hours > 7)
    {           
        totalCost = hours * 20;         
    }
    else
    {           
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid number.");           
    }

    return totalCost;       
}

public double calculateCost()
{       
    totalCost = hours + minutes;
    System.out.printf("The contract ID %s has specified %s for %d hours and %d minutes will equate to %.2f", contractID, rental, hours, minutes, totalCost);

    return totalCost;       
}
```

}

**SammysRentalsV2**
package program7;

//Main Method ~ Driver Class

public class SammysRentalsV2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    SammysContract contracts = new SammysContract();

    contracts.printWelcome();
    contracts.inputContract();
    contracts.rentalItem();
    contracts.hourID();
    contracts.minuteID();
    contracts.calculateCost();      
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are re-declaring your variables as local variables in your functions

```
public String inputContract()
{

    System.out.print("Please enter your contract ID: ");
    String contractID = userInput.nextLine(); // wrong one , local variable  
    contractID = userInput.nextLine(); // should be this 
    return contractID;
}
```

Strings are objects so default value is `null` due to `static/initialization` and by default `static int` are initialize as `0` so don't re declare them and problem solved

local variables can only be used inside that function in which they are declared so their value and reference will be lost after the function execution.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for bothering you but, I'm getting a logical error with errors with the hours. What do you think that could be? The math is wrong.

Comment: I planned on just had to wait for the timer.

Comment: @LeonKenedy great , i appreciate it and  happy coding

Comment: Sorry I thought it was formatted correctly. Sorry, for the inconvenience. But, could you help me please?

Comment: @LeonKenedy i just did , what's the issue now ?

Comment: The math for hours is wrong. I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: what exactly you desire ? or maybe all you want is this `hours >= 3 && hours <=5` try using  `&&` instead of `|`

Comment: I need the user to enter a price and the amount being charged is dependent how many hours they want. For instance all hours less than 3 is 35 per hour. While each minute equals 1 dollar.

Comment: @LeonKenedy simply it is like a grading program , so try this link http://codescracker.com/java/program/java-program-calculate-student-grade.htm and read how `elseif` works and simply replace grading logic with your hour-minute logic